# Не видимый padding

Tags: html, css, frontend, sass

Во всех браузерах кроме Firefox у блока появляется **не заданный padding**.
Обнуления отступов не работает даже с максимальным приоритетом.Изменения длины не помогло.
**Важно** у блока свойство ***overflow: scroll;*** и при отключении этого стиля проблема пропадает но макет требует его присутствия.

[image]

Comment: чем конкретно вам это мешает? Специально воспроизвела у себя аналогичную ситуацию. Зеленым окрашивается просто незанятое место в родительском блоке. Если добавить контента - зеленое место уменьшается до минимума, работает скролл как и задумано, и за пределы блока ничего не выходит.

Comment: Мешает тем что занимает огромное место которого нет в макете. Этого пространства просто не должно быть. Добавление li ничего не дало. Изменения длины родителя исправило ошибку во всех браузер, но в Firefox скрол с контентом просто вышел из контейнера.

Comment: приведите здесь код, пожалуйста, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему. Потому что просто по описанию ничего не понятно.